# Locking records in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, locking, block

Is it possible to lock a particular record in a MySQL Table?

I have this structure for table "categories" which has an Internal Relation with "id" of that same table (for nested and parent-child categories):

```
CREATE TABLE `dokumenti`.`categories` (
`id` INT( 9 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`categoryId` INT( 9 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
INDEX ( `categoryId` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`categoryId` by default can be `0` or `NULL` value.

Is it possible to insert a record like this:

```
INSERT INTO categories VALUES(0, 0, 'Root Level Category', 'Root Level Category')
```

**And to lock it so it cannot be DELETED, UPDATED or ALTERED?**

Comment: Yes.  Just don't write code to delete update or alter it :) Seriously though, if you will be doing certain table operations across multiple rows in a table, perhaps you can add your own flag field for such records that should not be tocuhed and then just make sure your updates, deletes, etc. don't touch row with this flag.

Comment: well I have tought about it already :) why I am asking this is because this app. is going to be used by alot of users,  who might mistakenly delete the record from "mysql" command or "phpMyAdmin".. from my application it will be disallowed to touch this record in any sense, except reading it :) thanks on the tips though!

Comment: Then just give user credentials to the those users that do not include CRUD privileges on that table.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a permanent "lock", you can have a look to the ["Archive" engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html)